# Копирование родительской папки в дочернюю

Tags: ubuntu, файлы

Всем привет , интересует правильный вариант , как скопировать родительскую папку ( все содержимое ) , в ее дочернюю папку ?
ubuntu 16.04.
пробовал 
`cp -rp /home/hp/test /home/hp/test/test1`

Все копировает , да только ругается вовремя копирования.

Интересует правильный вариант

Comment: А что вы ожидаете увидеть? Приведите пример структуры папок до/после.

Answer (score 2):

наиболее логично будет сначала скопировать каталог не «внутрь» самого себя, а «рядом», а затем переместить копию в нужное место:

```
$ cp -rp test test1
$ mv test1 test
```

---

### другой вариант

если вы используете в качестве оболочки программу *bash*, можно воспользоваться «расширенным шаблоном» (опция оболочки *extglob*, по умолчанию отключена) вида `!(шаблон)`, под который подпадут все файлы/каталоги, **не** соответствующие указанному шаблону. заодно стоит включить и опцию *dotglob* (тоже отключена по умолчанию), чтобы под шаблоны подпадали и файлы/каталоги, имена которых начинаются с точки. включение:

```
$ shopt -s extglob dotglob
```

копирование:

```
$ mkdir test/test1
$ cp -rp test/!(test1) test/test1
```