# как переместить все папки кроме нескольких?

Tags: linux, bash

как можно через консоль **linux**  переместить командой mv все папки кроме определенных папок в другую деректорию ?

Comment: [идентичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/639519/178576), но, формально, не является дубликатом, т.к. там речь про удаление, а не перемещение (что для решения задачи «исключить некоторые» не имеет значения).

Comment: другой в той же степени *идентичный* [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575844/178576)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ find откуда -mindepth 1 maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name каталог1 -exec mv {} куда \;
```

- `откуда` — каталог-источник (если текущий, то можно опустить)
- `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` — минимальная и максимальная глубина поиска
- `-type d` — тип «каталог»
- `-not -name имя` — пропустить указанное `имя`. конструкций `-not -name имя` может быть и несколько подряд, с разными именами
- `-exec команда \;` — для всего найденого выполнить указанную команду
- `куда` — каталог, в который надо переместить найденое

---

идентичный вопрос, но, формально, не является дубликатом, т.к. там речь про удаление, а не перемещение (что для решения задачи «исключить некоторые» не имеет значения): [Удаление файлов и папок кроме некоторых](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/639519/178576)

другой в той же степени *идентичный* вопрос: [Копирование родительской папки в дочернюю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575844/178576)

Comment: можно задать «как выполнить X команду для всех папок кроме нескольких» для каждой X команды, которая с папками работает ;)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно всего-лишь потренироваться в **bash**, поучить синтаксис, не всё так и сложно. Делаем цикл файлов в директории, выбор вариантов и действия.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *; do
  if [ -d "$file" ]; then
    case $file in
      неменя|нет|прикольная)
        echo "пропускаем $file"
        ;;
      *)
        echo "перемещаем $file"
        mv $file кудато
        ;;
    esac;
  else
    echo "$file не папка";
  fi
done
```

Comment: В вашем примере как минимум две ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

При включённой опции `extglob`, можно так:

```
$ shopt extglob
extglob off
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls
a b c
$ mv !(c) foo
$ ls
c
$ ls foo
a b
```

Comment: в вопросе-то речь **только** про каталоги.